# python How to create a dictionary from a list

Tags: python

The dictionary should have keys equal to the number, value equals to the corresponding title.

```
str1 = ['Program ONE', 
        '1001 Transfiguration. ', 
        '1100 Charms.', 
        '1250 Defence Against the Dark Arts.', 
        '1380 Potions. ', 
        '1420 Arithmancy.', 
        '2075 Flying. ']
```

Comment: What if there is no number, like in `'Program ONE'`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: If you simply trouble to Google your question title, you'll get many useful hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is basic string handling.

What's the pseudo-code:

```
For each item in <str1>:
    split out the number
    split out the course-name
    add number:course to a dictionary
```

Giving the code:

```
course_dict = {}
for pair in str1:
    course_number, course_name = pair.split(' ', 1)  # TODO: handle double-spaces, etc.
    course_dict[course_number] = course_name
```

It always helps to jot down a bit of pseudo-code to help get your thoughts around the task.  The key thing in this code is the `split(' ', 1)` - this makes only one split because of that second parameter.

So - what about that problematic first entry, how can we detect that?
Well, some basic error handling in the code will catch it, and it's always good to have better error handling.

```
course_dict = {}
for pair in str1:
    course_number, course_name = pair.split(' ', 1)  # TODO: handle double-spaces, etc.
    # Check that course_number is really a number
    try:
        num = int(course_number)
        # No error, so it was a number -> good to go
        course_dict[course_number] = course_name
    except:
        # it's not a number
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck on splitting

Answer (score 0):

First create a dictionary, like so:

```
my_dict = {}
```

Then iterate over your list. You can achieve that by:

```
for x in str1:
```

In your specific case (with the exception of `Program ONE`) the numbers appear first. They also have a length of four characters but let's consider a more general case. Inside the for loop, you could create a temporary list holding everything that's being separated by space, like so:

```
temp = x.split(" ")
```

For the second element in your original list, it's gonna look like that:

```
['1001', 'Transfiguration. ']
```

The number is the first element in the temporary list (of index 0). Everything else is the name of the course, so let's use `.join()` method to get a proper string back.

```
temp_str = " ".join(temp[1:])
```

What it does is that it selects all items starting with index 1 and up, and then joins them together using space as a delimeter.

So now let's add things to the dictionary. Defining new pairs follows the syntax `dictionary[key] = value`. Key is the first element of the temporary list, value is the newly created string, so everything that's left to do is to say:

```
my_dict[temp[0]] = temp_str
```